# How to display the data according to the time in cakephp2?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Currently, I use the sample script below to get the following list of array data. And is displayed in the following order.

$datas = $this->MyDataModel->getDataByArrayLists($listofids);

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [my_name] => Joe
                    [my_home] => home1
                    [my_school] => school1)
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [my_name] => Bob
                    [my_home] => home2
                    [my_school] => school2
```

What I want to do is to change the order of data to be displayed  according to the last clicked time. I don't want to do it in the database. The time is saved in a cookie data in the following format and planning to use it to sort the data. for example, (id 1 is Joe) and (id 2 is Bob) and if you see the above array data, Joe is displayed first and Bob is second. But as you can see in the following array that that the id 2's [time] is last clicked, Bob should be in 0 index in the data and Joe should be in the first index. The problem is that I dont know how I can change the position of the data of the indexes and show it.

```
 Array
      (
        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [time] => 2017-12-22 18:53:47
        )
        ,
        [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [time] => 2017-12-22 19:56:05
        )

)
```

Some sample or tips would be great! I would love to hear from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an optimized solution, you can work on that

```
    $a = array(
        'data' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Joe',
                'my_home' => 'Home 1'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Bob',
                'my_home' => 'Home 2'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Alice',
                'my_home' => 'Home 3'
            )
        )
    );

    $b = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'time' => '2017-12-22 18:53:47'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'time' => '2017-12-22 19:53:47'
        )
    );

    usort($a['data'], function($el1, $el2) use($b) {
        $t1 = Hash::get(Hash::extract($b, "{n}[id=" . $el1['id'] . "]"), '0.time', 0);
        $t2 = Hash::get(Hash::extract($b, "{n}[id=" . $el2['id'] . "]"), '0.time', 0);
        return (is_string($t1) ? strtotime($t1) : 0) < (is_string($t2) ? strtotime($t2) : 0) ;
    });
```